# "All pipe instances are busy" with PSEXEC

Tags: powershell, command-line, psexec

So that this doesn't cost you an hour of Googling around:

Problem: launching psexec (from Powershell) with
./psexec64 \targetip -s -u domain\username -p "password" c:\path\to\this\file.exe -accepteula

Result:
It seems to connect but you get All Pipe Instances Are Busy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution (at least in this case: The path to the executable on the target host has a typo.

Yup.  No shame.  We all do it.  Go fix your typo and enjoy the rest of your day.

On a related note, I couldn't shake the "the handle is invalid" error from the command prompt and worked around it by going to PowerShell.  Apologies for not having a good technical explanation as to why that's the case, but this has been bonus psexec material.